# How to execute a pool of tasks using set number of Java / Groovy threads without blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy

Right now I have this Groovy code to run a series of tasks:

```
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(tasks.size);

    for( task in tasks ) {
        Thread.start worker.curry(task, latch)
    }

    latch.await(300L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I'd like to limit the number of simultaneous threads to a certain number `t`.  The way it's written now, for `n` tasks, `n` threads get created "at once".  I thought about using multiple latches or some sort of callback, but couldn't come up with a good solution.

The solution should start new task threads as soon as running threads drops below `t`, until number running reaches `t` or there are no un-run tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Executor framework.

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(t);
```

This will create n and only n threads on start.  Then you can submit to the executor to utilize these threads.

Edit: Thanks for the comment Josh, I'll post your solution

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6); 
for( task in tasks ) { 
    pool.execute Worker.curry(task)
} 
pool.shutdown();
```

Comment: This worked for me. For the record, the code is `ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6); for( task in tasks ) {  pool.execute Worker.curry(task)} pool.shutdown();`

Answer (score 5):

You should check out [GPars](http://www.gpars.org/) and use one of the abstractions listed. You can then specify the number to create in withPool(). I like fork/join:

```
withPool(4) { pool ->
  runForkJoin(rootTask) { task ->
    task.eachTask { forkChild(task) }
  }
}
```